# Return sum of negative and positive floating point numbers

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, floating-point

I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of floating points and returns a list of two numbers, which is equal to the sum of all positive and all negative floating points. For example:

```
statement([30.95, -15.67, 45.56, -55.00, 43.78])
returns [-70.67, 120.29]
```

Here's what 've been able to do so far:

```
res= []
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    for j in range(i,len(l)):
        if l[i]>=l[i+1]:
            res = 
return res
```

But I'm kind of stuck. Can anyone help me understand this a little better?

Answer (score 5):

I'd filter them into two lists:

```
positives = [n for n in numbers if n < 0]
negatives = [n for n in numbers if n > 0]
```

And then use `sum()`:

```
return sum(negatives), sum(positives)
```

Or if you want to make your instructor mad:

```
statement = lambda n: map(sum, zip(*map(lambda x: (x, 0)[::cmp(0, x)], n)))
```

Comment: the conditions are reversed

Answer (score 5):

```
def sum_negpos(numbers):
    return [sum(n for n in numbers if n < 0), # sum of negative numbers
            sum(n for n in numbers if n > 0)] # sum of positive numbers
```

The solution uses generator expressions `(x for x in it if cond(x))` that use the same syntax as [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) `[x for x in it if cond(x)]` but yuild one value at a time instead of creating a whole list at once.

In a single pass:

```
def sum_negpos(numbers):
    sums = [0, 0] # negative, positive sum
    for n in numbers:
        sums[n > 0] += n
    return sums
```

This solution exploits the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0` in Python therefore `sums[n > 0]` is `sums[1]` if `n > 0` and it is `sums[0]` otherwise.

Comment: Thank You! Can you explain how you arrived at the solution?

Comment: @user2101463: I've added an explanation

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution:

```
def statement(l):
    return reduce(lambda (n, p), x: (x < 0) and (n + x, p) \
        or (n, p + x), l, (0, 0))

statement([30.95, -15.67, 45.56, -55.00, 43.78])
(-70.67, 120.29)
```

Comment: to support Python 3: [`functools.reduce(lambda s, n: (s[0] + n, s[1]) if n < 0 else (s[0] , s[1] + n) , L, (0, 0)) if L else (0, 0)`](http://ideone.com/q4JCiM)